# Erro ao desinstalar Passport Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Eu tinha instalado o Passport do Laravel, mas, resolvi trabalhar com o JWT (removi via composer)
Agora o Laravel não está localizando minhas funções no controller
O que eu devo fazer?
Parece que eu tenho que alterar alguma configuração

```
BadMethodCallException: Method [getEstudantesTodos] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\TurmasController]. in file C:\sgeweb\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 68
```

Comment: Me parece que o erro não tem nenhuma relação com o problema do seu controller. Poderia editar a pergunta e fornecer mais informações? Como por exemplo, a versão do laravel usada, os pacotes do composer...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Realmente não tem haver com o controller. Estava funcionando tudo bem até eu desinstalar o Passport Meu Laravel é 5.6

Comment: Sim, mas como você diz que o problema é no Passport mas está falando que não tem a ver com o controller, sendo que o código mostrado na pergunta é um erro referente a um controller?

Comment: Se você instalar o Passport de novo, resolve? Se não, já sabemos que o problema não é por aí. Talvez você esteja falando da configuração do `config/auth.php`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters É o erro que apareceu depois que eu desinstalei. O Laravel não está aceitando o caminho do controller

Comment: Na verdade, a mensagens de erro está bem clara: "Método getEstudantesTodos não existe no App\Http\Controllers\TurmasController no arquivo ...Controller.php .  O problema é que tem um método que está sendo buscado por uma rota que simplesmente não existe.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Existe sim. Estava funcionando normalmente até que eu desinstalei o Passport. Eu criei um novo controller para testar e funcionou. Me parece que quando eu desinstalei o Passport ocorreu algum problema na configuração dos Controllers

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Tem algum problema na configuração do Laravel que perdeu a rota das funções dos controllers ao desinstalar o Passport. Eu criei um outro controle e copiei todo o Controller anterior e mudei a rota e funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode remover o passport manualmente excluindo a linha "laravel / passport":"....." no seu arquivo composer.json, em seguida, execute a atualização do composer, utilizando composer update.

Certifique-se de remover referencias no arquivo app.config - Laravel \ Passport \ PassportServiceProvider :: class

E todas as classes que dependem do passport também devem ser editadas. As classes mais comuns são:

Models de usuário, traits HasApiToken.
AuthServiceProvider, remova o Passport :: routes (); no seu método de inicialização.